# Return data using BeginReceive to another method in different class

Tags: c#, asynchronous, udp, beginreceive

I'm using the following code to receive a datagram asynchronously in a class named `UDPComm`. 
what I do is the following:

1. I have another class named `Manager` which sends a message over the UDP connection `UPComm.send(byte[])`
2. Then it calls `UDPComm.startListening()` to listen the message.

My problem is, how can I pass the received bytes in `receive()` method to `Manager` class? I tried to add a return but it give me an error in `udp.BeginReceive(receive, new object())`.

Your help is highly appreciated.

```
   private void startListening()
    {
        try
        {
            ar_ = udp.BeginReceive(receive, new object());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception in StartListening()" 
                                                   + e.ToString());
        }
    }


   `private void receive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        byte[] bytes = udp.EndReceive(ar, ref networkEndpointIp);
    }`
```

Comment: Raise an event named something like `DataReceived`? which you will be subscribing from `Manager` class

Comment: Thank you @SriramSakthivel for the hint. I was able to define a custom event and subscribe the `Manager` class to it. Thank you!